# Should the [brushed-dc] tag be renamed to something more meaningful?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just stumbled upon the [brushed-dc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brushed-dc) tag which is attached to 5 questions about brushed dc-motors.

The tag has no description and in itself is a bit obscure, especially for beginners.

I think it would be better to rename it to *brushed-dc-motor*.

**EDIT**

It seems that this post as attracted a mild appreciation. In absence of strong manifested opposition I'll do the renaming.

Comment: No.  Stop making trivial edits to old low quality questions - there's not enough improvement to justify all the undeserved attention called to them by being bumped up on the main page.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Sorry, but I couldn't retag without editing the posts, and I did a thorough edit just to avoid just a retag. I thought I'll be fine since I followed the guidelines of SE network stated [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51767/retagging-bumping-etiquette) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38987/how-many-retags-should-you-do-before-asking-a-moderator).

Comment: The motor could be operating as a generator .This is why the term "Machine" is sometimes used.

Comment: @Autistic agreed, but in the specific case all the 5 questions were about motors. Anyway I think that if we need a more general tag, we should name it brushed-dc-machine. Simply "brushed-dc" is not informative enough, and hampers searchability IMO (especially for beginners).